# XLST new line insert does not work as expected with Hive

Tags: xml, csv, xslt, hadoop, hive

I am converting a xml to csv using xslt, here is my xsl file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:cov="http://schemas.atlassian.com/clover3/report">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="testcase">
  <xsl:value-of select ="@classname"/>
  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text> 
  <xsl:value-of select ="@name"/>
  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text> 
  <xsl:value-of select ="@time"/>  
  <xsl:text>&#xD;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The csv file looks good, all the new lines are there, but when I try to create an external table with Hive (from Cloudera Hadoop) using this query:

```
Create external table csv_test(className STRING, testName STRING, duration DOUBLE)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LOCATION '/TEST/';
```

For each line in my csv file, I have two lines, one with values and the other one with NULLs. As if it wasn not taking the line change correctly and was thinking it was two lines instead of one.

I tried different tricks for the new line, such as `&#10;`, `&#xa;`, `&#xd;`, `&#13;`, `\n`, combinations of the preceding codes and even placing the  tags on two separtate lines, but I have the same result.

The other issue is with the third field, the duration. I always have a NULL value. In my create table query, if I replace DOUBLE by STRING, it works.

Everything (new lines and DOUBLE) works fine if I create my cvs file manually with the same data, the issue if only with the csv file created by the xslt.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What about the file length in bytes of the generated file? Does that reflect what you see in the editor? Maybe it's a coding problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a python script to read the xml file and write a csv file. I had no format issue proceeding this way...

Comment: Glad you found a solution, though this preprocessing should not be necessary. If your XML was valid, whitespace handling should be smooth. Still wondering what could've possibly been the issue that caused you so much trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Newline handling between different systems and programs can be tricky. You should check the following to determine where it goes wrong:

- When the XML is read by the processor, its newlines are all converted to 0x0A, that is, Windows newlines (0x0D + 0x0A) are converted to 0x0A, any remaining single 0x0D (Mac newline) are then replaced by 0x0A.
- If you do not explicitly use `xsl:stripspace` or remove empty text nodes with matching patterns, the default matching patterns will output the whitespace. In your example above, as written, newlines of the input XML would become part of the output XML.
- Even if double newlines are physically present, many text-editors will normalize them before displaying them. For instance, in your example, if the input contained newlines, the output could contain sequences of 0xA + 0xD, which, if viewed in Windows *looks* like a single newline, but may not be interpreted like a single newline on other systems.
- After you get everything right in the transformation, it depends on how you move the output to the final location. If you use FTP, or Github, newlines can be converted. You can fix this by moving them explicitly as binary files.
- Some XSLT 1.0 processors exist that will normalize line-endings when you output with `method="text"` to match the default line-endings for the platform you are on (which is not correct behavior, but that is another story). You don't mention the processor you use, but you can check this by opening the resulting file as binary and verify you only have 0xA line endings.
- Usually, the safest is to stick to the same line-endings regime for all your systems and prevent implicit conversions when files are uploaded from one system to another.
- *Update*, apparently, Hive [currently automatically normalizes line-endings](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-2254), which means you either hit a bug of Hive, you use a non-stable build of Hive or your output contains actual stuff that causes the null-records to appear. For the latter, we need to have a minimal, but fully working input XML and XSLT that you currently use to try to reproduce your issue.

The issue with the `DOUBLE` field is tricky. It may depend on localization settings, but I don't know enough of Hive to proof that. Suppose your localization is German, a double value is written as 23.456,98, which in English locales would be 23,456.98. Check the CSV for what format it has and whether it matches the expected output, or convert the dots into commas or the converse.

An example of your XSLT that removes any whitespace from the input can look as follows (other options possible):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:cov="http://schemas.atlassian.com/clover3/report">

    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="testcase">
      <xsl:value-of select ="@classname"/>
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text> 
      <xsl:value-of select ="@name"/>
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text> 
      <xsl:value-of select ="@time"/>  
      <xsl:text>&#xD;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- remove unmatched text nodes -->
    <xsl:template match="text()" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried removing whitespaces, among other things, this week, but it does the same thing (I even have two '?' chars at the beginning of the first field of the first row, maybe some kind of start of file char in the file). I don't think the DOUBLE issue is a localization one since when I type '0.222' manually in the file, it works. I tried writing a file with a python script and Hive is interpreting it correctly, so I might try to convert the xml file with a python script instead.

Comment: @Amaranth: I wonder what processor you are using. The question marks sound like byte order marks for UTF-8 or UTF-16. Are you actually outputing text, or is it set to XML? It is possible that you get different results if you set the encoding of `xsl:output` to something else (it defaults to UTF-8), like `ISO-8859-1` for instance?